# Page loading time - preloading images and lazy-loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-loading

I am creating an ecommerce site. However, the more products we add the more images we need to display on a page and it is starting to slow down the site.

What I have done so far to combat this is first I preload all of the images with PHP like so:

```
foreach(glob("media/product_images/*") as $file) {
    if(filetype($file) != 'dir'){
        echo '<link rel="preload" href="'.$file.'" as="image">';
    }
}
```

I then tried this lazy-loading technique I found online with `JS/jquery/CSS` like so:

JS/jquery:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]'), function(img){
    img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('data-src'));
    img.onload = function(){
        img.removeAttribute('data-src');
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<img data-src='../path/to/image.png'>
```

CSS:

```
img{
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 0.3s;
}
img[data-src]{
    opacity:0;
}
```

I'm not sure what best practices for this would be, I've found a few different ways of doing this but not sure what is best.

Comment: Hi you can use the browser's `Intersection Observer API` to evaluate if images are below the fold and update their `src` attribute when the are actually in the viewport: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API
BUT it's not supported in all browsers so you need to find a workaround
https://caniuse.com/#search=intersection

Comment: @t3__rry. Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately we're selling industrial lifting equipment so alot of our customers are still using really old versioins of IE, and I mean REALLY OLD... like painfully old to develop for :(

Comment: You're welcome, I've found a polyfill on Github: https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill
I haven't tested it though

Comment: @t3__rry thanks again I'll look into this and see how I get on